# how can I mode rewrite this url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mod_rewrite: rewrite to “pretty URL”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245831/mod-rewrite-rewrite-to-pretty-url)

I want to mod-rewrite this url

http://www.mywebsite.com/art/p.php?id=180 
to 
http://www.mywebsite.com/art/180

Can anyone tell me how this can be done in .htaccess file?

Comment: Take a look at some of the other questions covering this topic. It has been answered several times before. Here's one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245831/mod-rewrite-rewrite-to-pretty-url

Answer (score 0):

If you want a user to be able to type in http://www.mywebsite.com/art/180 and actually see the output of http://www.mywebsite.com/art/p.php?id=180 then you can use the following:-

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^art/(\d+)/?$          art/p.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

If you want to redirect users who type http://www.mywebsite.com/art/p.php?id=180 to http://www.mywebsite.com/art/180 then you can use the following:-

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}        ^id=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^art/p\.php$           /art/%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Make sense?