# PHP/Apache - Building a different URL, can it be done?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm looking into how to build a different URL, and I was wondering if it is possible to replace the query-string/question mark symbol PHP uses in URLs which is the '?' into something else? For example an exclamation mark '!'

www.example.com!foo=1

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod_rewrite: rewrite to "pretty URL"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245831/mod-rewrite-rewrite-to-pretty-url)

Comment: What purpose is the `!` suppose to serve?  The purpose of `?`?  If so, why are you trying to change a web standard?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you'll need rewrite rules to tell the server how to serve them. And PHP won't parse them automatically for you, so $_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST variables won't get set and you'll have to parse them yourself from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use mod_rewrite for this, because you can still interpret the url with $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] or $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] depending on your configuration. Just split it at the ! with [explode](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) and parse it with [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-str.php). It is your decision if this makes sense.

You should be able to replace it by htaccess too but I am unable to test it because I have no apache running atm. Must be something like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^!(.*)$ http://domain.com/?$1 [R,NC]
```

If this works, remove the "R," from the rule.

Comment: I just saw. This will only replace yourdomain.com/!anyinput. Maybe you will need something like this too `RewriteRule ^(.*)!(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1?$2 [R,NC]`