# Can't get forward slash .htaccess redirect to work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to do the following redirect, but cannot get this working, any help appreciated:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^service-pricing$ index.php?rp=/service/pricing/ [NC]
```

The above just results in the page cannot be found.

Comment: What is the URL you're testing? Do you have an `index.php` file?

Comment: I am trying to rewrite the URL from www.domain.com/index.php?rp=/service/pricing/ to the following: www.domain.com/service-pricing

Comment: If you want to rewrite in that direction, you might need a different approach. See [Rewrite to “pretty URL”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245888/924299) or [PHP .htaccess -> pretty url (in reverse)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5573650/924299).

Comment: @Linuc82 You wouldn't normally rewrite in that direction (as stated in your comment)? (Redirect maybe; rewrite no). The directive in your question actually "looks ok", providing you are requesting the the URL `/service-pricing`. Does it "work" if you don't use "forward slashes" (the way your question is worded implies that it does)? Can you confirm the full URL-path of the file accepting this request (ie. `index.php`) and the location of this `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other directives in this `.htaccess` file? Are `.htaccess` files enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You miss understood how rewriting works. The rules do *not* somehow magically convert references you send out. Instead they get appled on *incoming* requests.

Here is the approach that should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rp=/service/pricing/?$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /service-pricing [END]
```

You definitely should start reading into the documentation of the tool you use. As typical for OpenSource projects it is of excelent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html